# Cant seem to get https and socks proxies to work using python requests

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

So I'm looking at traffic using wireshark and comparing the output for a number of situations. I'm only looking at traffic between me and google.co.za.

**Situation 1: Accessing google.co.za using no proxy**

```
requests.get('www.google.co.za')
```

This returns a response with status=200 and wireshark displays info about traffic passing between my pc and google's servers. This is great so far.

**Situation 2: Accessing google.co.za using valid http proxy**

```
requests.get("http://google.co.za",proxies={'http':proxy})
```

This returns a response with status=200 and wireshark displays *no* data about traffic passing between my pc and google's servers. This is great and expected and stuff.

**Situation 3: Accessing google.co.za using valid socks proxy**

```
requests.get("http://google.co.za",proxies={'socks':proxy})
```

result as per situation 1. Hmmm

**Situation 4: same deal with https**

```
requests.get("http://google.co.za",proxies={'https':proxy})
```

same result as situation 1.

**Question**

So it looks like when I try to use https and socks proxies requests acts as though the proxy argument is empty. Now I need to pass traffic through all sorts of proxies and I don't want any silent failures.

My question is: Why is stuff failing silently and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Requests` simply does not yet support either SOCKS or HTTPS proxies.

They're working in it, though. See here: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/pull/1515

Support for HTTPS proxies has already been merged into the `requests 2.0` branch, so if you like you can try that version; be wary though, as it it is currently an unstable branch.

SOCKS proxy support, on the other hand, is still being worked on in the lower-level library, `urllib3`: https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/pull/68

Also, regardless of that, you are using the `proxies` argument incorrectly. It should be of the form `{protocol_of_sites_you_visit: proxy}`, so once support is complete, using a SOCKS5 proxy would actually be more along the lines of `{"http": "socks5://127.0.0.1:9050"}`.